# Validating ui:fragments

Tags: java, validation, jsf

How can validate this code that user enter a valid ip address i want show message when user enter `0.0.0.0`  i can use a request scoped bean and register it for all inputtext in inputtadress fragment and check 4  inputtext field but i want to know is there any other way .

```
     <ui:fragment >
                    <ui:include src="/misc/inputaddress.xhtml">
                        <ui:param name="id" value="ip" />
                        <ui:param name="value"
                                  value="#{externalDataStorageAdder.storage.inputAddr}"
                                  />

                    </ui:include>
                </ui:fragment>
```

and this inputaddres

```
<div
    style="border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; background-color: #ffffff; width: 162px;">
<h:inputText id="#{id}-field1"
    style="width: 25px; border: 0px; text-align: center; background-color: white; background-image: url('');"
    maxlength="3" value="#{value.field1}" onfocus="this.select();"
    onkeyup="number_only(this);">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="255" />
</h:inputText> . <h:inputText id="#{id}-field2"
    style="width: 25px; border: 0px; text-align: center; background-color: white; background-image: url('');"
    maxlength="3" value="#{value.field2}" onfocus="this.select();"
    onkeyup="number_only(this);">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="255" />
</h:inputText> . <h:inputText id="#{id}-field3"
    style="width: 25px; border: 0px; text-align: center; background-color: white; background-image: url('');"
    maxlength="3" value="#{value.field3}" onfocus="this.select();"
    onkeyup="number_only(this);">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="255" />
</h:inputText> . <h:inputText id="#{id}-field4"
    style="width: 25px; border: 0px; text-align: center; background-color: white; background-image: url('');"
    maxlength="3" value="#{value.field4}" onfocus="this.select();"
    onkeyup="number_only(this);">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="255" />
</h:inputText></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `validator` , [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html) is very nice article from BalusC

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own validator like Joshi suggested (in fact, I used that BalusC article as well) or just check the ip-address in the action and post a message if "0.0.0.0" was entered.

What we normally do is to do a syntax check on individual fields in the validation phase and a more throrough semantic check (multiple fields in combination) in the invoke application phase.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check it in the bean you can do it with javascript. Call a javascript function each time a key is pressed in your input field and check in your function if all inputfields contain zero:

```
<h:inputText id="..." onkeypress="keyPressed();" .../>
```

and in your script:

```
function keyPressed() {  
 check for zero content
}
```